# Rolling six month, distinct count, of number of individuals

Tags: count, distinct, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate the number of distinct contacts interacted with in the previous six months for each month.
I require to do this for particular organisations and overall.

In layman's terms an example would be as follows:
April 2023 = number of distinct contacts interacted with between November 2022 to April 2023
March 2023 = number of distinct contacts interacted with between October 2022 to March 2023
as so on.

Thus, I can calculate if the number of distinct contacts interacted with is increasing or decreasing over time.

So far I have:

SELECT
date_trunc('month', add_months(activity_date, 6)) AS meeting_month,
COUNT(DISTINCT contact_salesforce_id) AS unique_people
FROM interactions
WHERE org_name = 'Company A'
Group by meeting_month

The query produces a result, the wrong result.
I don't think it is doing what I want.

Any ideas?